# unity script stops updating after 20 seconds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, timing

Title says it all. Working on some animation scripting. Using a supercounter that increments every frame and running my timing off that so I can use proportions for timing reasons.

Decent amount of googleing lead to a bit on making meta files visable but I tried that and nothing came out of it

This is the last piece of the file just before it freezes.
I've printed it out and physically looked for any errors and would like a second pair of eyes.

```
        if (superCounter > 550 && superCounter < 750) {
            //transformBarrel(0,-barrelAcceleration* 2 *Time.deltaTime, 100 ,2);
            transformBarrel(barrelAcceleration * Time.deltaTime * 2, 0, 0, 2);
            // barrel 2 down needs to happen after x translataion
            //   transformBarrel(0,-barrelAcceleration * 5f * Time.deltaTime, 0, 2); // moves the 2nd barrel forward

            transformBarrel(-barrelAcceleration, 0, 0, 2);

        }
        if (Time.fixedTime > 19 && Time.fixedTime < 25) {
            appleInstance.transform.Translate(Vector3.down * 3 * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
            bananaInstance.transform.Translate(Vector3.down * 3 * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
            Debug.Log(Time.fixedTime);

        }
```

Comment: Is this code located in `FixedUpdate` or `Update`? Please elaborate more on what you are trying to achieve. There's no way of telling from this code snippet why the script stops after 20s. I can only assume that you want to handle two animations in one update function (that's what you maybe need the supercounter for). If that's the case, maybe coroutines are the more elegant solution for your problem.

Comment: Is this C# or UnityScript?